# how store data in session for HTML pages

Tags: html

how to store data in session for HTML

For IE 8 and mozilla we have like "sessionStorage" but it doesnot work for IE7 and below

is there something that i can use that will work for all version of IE and mozilla

Answer (score 1):

Use either cookies or server side sessions. DOM storage is supported only by the newest browsers.